# Fastest way to get the probabilties for which an element is present in a list

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I created a function that will return a dictionary with the input list elements and the probability of selecting that item from the list:

```
from collections import Counter

def proba(x):
    n = len(x)
    return {key: val/n for key, val in dict(Counter(x)).items()}
```

Is there a faster solution to this ? I don't need the output to be in a kay:value pair if the output order of probabilities corresponds to the input order of elements.

Comment: I don't think so. `Counter` is already highly optimized, so your `proba(x)` function's complexity is already `O(n)` in time - which is most optimized. If you want to optimize further in space, you can improve the `dict(Counter(x))` a bit by construct the dictionary yourself, so there's only one object needed rather than 2 objects.

Comment: More information about how you will use this function would be helpful.  What is the data type of the values in the input list?  Integers?  Strings? Something else?  Also, what is a typical value for `len(x)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP/blob/master/numpy_indexed/funcs.py) package (disclaimer: I am its author) provides generalizations of the numpy arraysetops module; including utilities to solve your problem in an elegant and vectorized manner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
keys, counts = npi.count(x)
proba = counts / len(x)
```

Not sure how it stacks up in terms of performance to Counter; which is quite well optimized I believe. However, in the case that the elements of x can themselves be represented as an ndarray, I expect this method to pull ahead.

Comment: if the input is `np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=50000)` your method outperforms the function I wrote by 5.24 ms

Comment: Glad to help; to expand on my last remark, you could try `np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(50000, 2))`, which should work just the same, but is likely to bog down and non-vectorized solution

Answer (score 2):

In a comment to Eelco's answer, you wrote

> if the input is np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=50000) ...

`numpy_indexed` has some powerful tools, but for data like that, you can get better performance using [`numpy.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

```
In [11]: import numpy as np

In [12]: import numpy_indexed as npi

In [13]: x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=50000)
```

Here's the calculation using `numpy.bincount`.  The result is an array with length `x.max()+1`.

```
In [14]: np.bincount(x)/len(x)
Out[14]: 
array([ 0.01066,  0.01022,  0.01048,  0.00994,  0.01026,  0.00972,
        0.0107 ,  0.00962,  0.0098 ,  0.00922,  0.00996,  0.01038,
        0.01024,  0.01118,  0.01012,  0.01098,  0.00988,  0.00996,
        0.00974,  0.0097 ,  0.00994,  0.01004,  0.0099 ,  0.01034,
        0.01066,  0.01032,  0.01042,  0.00896,  0.00958,  0.01008,
        0.01038,  0.00974,  0.01068,  0.00952,  0.00998,  0.00932,
        0.00964,  0.0103 ,  0.0099 ,  0.0093 ,  0.0101 ,  0.01012,
        0.0097 ,  0.00988,  0.0099 ,  0.01076,  0.01008,  0.0097 ,
        0.00986,  0.00998,  0.00976,  0.00984,  0.01008,  0.01008,
        0.00938,  0.00998,  0.00976,  0.0093 ,  0.00974,  0.00958,
        0.00984,  0.01032,  0.00988,  0.01014,  0.01088,  0.01006,
        0.0097 ,  0.01026,  0.00952,  0.01002,  0.00938,  0.01024,
        0.01024,  0.00984,  0.00922,  0.01044,  0.0101 ,  0.01052,
        0.01002,  0.00996,  0.0101 ,  0.00976,  0.00986,  0.01062,
        0.01064,  0.01008,  0.00992,  0.00972,  0.01006,  0.01026,
        0.01018,  0.01044,  0.0092 ,  0.00982,  0.00994,  0.00958,
        0.00958,  0.01012,  0.01024,  0.00996])
```

Here's a comparison of the timing; note the change in the units of the results:

```
In [24]: %timeit npi.count(x)[1]/len(x)
1.35 ms ± 1.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [25]: %timeit np.bincount(x)/len(x)
76.1 µs ± 124 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer it is indeed much faster but it is too restrictive in terms of inputs. while Eelco's answer works on strings, all ints and all floats (though floats don't make much sense). sorry I did not respond to your comment on my question. in any case this is def useful

Answer (score 1):

This method beats yours 97.6% of the time:

```
def proba_2(x):
    n = len(x)
    single_prob = 1/n
    d = {}
    for i in x:
        if i in d:
            d[i] += single_prob
        else:
            d[i] = single_prob
    return d
```

Although not by any significant margin (the average difference over 1000 runs is `0.006`). In essence, your code is algorithmically optimized (being that it's `O(n)`, and all that's left is micro-optimizations.

Full testing code:

```
from collections import Counter
from timeit import Timer
import random

def proba_1(x):
    n = len(x)
    return {key: val/n for key, val in dict(Counter(x)).items()}

def proba_2(x):
    n = len(x)
    single_prob = 1/n
    d = {}
    for i in x:
        if i in d:
            d[i] += single_prob
        else:
            d[i] = single_prob
    return d


t = Timer(lambda: proba_1(l))
t_2 = Timer(lambda: proba_2(l))

p1 = 0
p2 = 0

total_diff = 0.0

for i in range(1,1001):
    l = [random.randrange(1,101,1) for _ in range (100)]
    if i % 2 == 0:
        proba_1_time = t.timeit(number=10000)
        proba_2_time = t_2.timeit(number=10000)
    else:
        proba_2_time = t_2.timeit(number=10000)
        proba_1_time = t.timeit(number=10000)

    print(proba_1(l),proba_1_time, proba_2(l), proba_2_time)
    if proba_1_time < proba_2_time:
        print("Proba_1 wins: " + str(proba_1_time))
        p1 += 1
    else:
        print("Proba_2 wins: " + str(proba_2_time))
        p2 += 1
    total_diff += abs(proba_1_time - proba_2_time)

    print(p1,p2, total_diff/i)
```